# Change "\\server\printer" to "printer on server:"

Tags: c#, string

I have a string `"\\server\printer"` and I need to change it to `"printer on server:"

please note that "server and printer can vary in lengths.

Comment: So strip characters 0-1, and split on slashes (`string.Split("\")`).

Comment: What have you *tried* besides reading forums for hours?

Comment: This seems easily doable. You should put some effort into your problem. If you did put in effort, then show that in your question.

Comment: yourstring = yourstring.Remove(0,1); string[] split = yourstring.Split('\'); will be usefull

Comment: Do you need to replace the whole contents of the string or a specific part? You do not specify *exactly* what needs to be changed.

Comment: Please try some code with the information you now have and post it if you still can't figure it out

Comment: note you cannot split on "\" , you need @"\"

Comment: I smell homework assignment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var incomingText = @"\\server\printer";
var split = incomingText.Split(new[] { '\\' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
var decoratedText = split[1] + " on " + split[0];
```

Comment: It would be better to use methods from the [`Path` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.aspx).

Comment: Looks wrong. output would be something like: `" on "` because "\\" is two '\\' as well

Comment: @doogle StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries takes care of that :)

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen yes this would be better. Could you please show how to do it properly?

Comment: @CanBaycay sorry missed that.

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] split = yourString.Split("\\");
Return split[1] + " on " + split[0];
```

Comment: This will give `server\printer on` !

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZsjrsN

```
    var str = @"\\server\printer";
    var matches = Regex.Match(str, @"[A-Za-z0-9]{1,}");
    string str1 = matches.Value;
    matches = matches.NextMatch();
    string str2 = matches.Value;
    string result = str2 + " on " + str1;
```